# Clean way to detect collision of object with box2d

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I have been looking into box2d (in java with libgdx) lately and have been trying to create my own custom bounce effect (I increase the `Restitution` after the first bounce)

To do this as a test I simply checked the location of the object and waited for the first bounce.

But now I wanted to actually implement this and came across a problem: How to detect the collision of 2 specific object in box2d?

I found this tutorial: 
[box2d collision detection](http://blog.allanbishop.com/box2d-2-1a-tutorial-%E2%80%93-part-4-collision-detection/) - but I am very reluctant to use that code. There must be a simpler and cleaner way to detect a collision between 2 objects (without having to set user data and checking all collisions with giant `if()` conditions...)

Can anyone help me out?  (assuming I am not just hopeful and there actually is a better way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `b2ContactListener` class to handle the collision and reimplement collision callbacks. Then just:

```
MyContactListener *listener = new MyContactListener();
myB2World->SetContactListener(listener);
```

Comment: @user2372006: it is c++. In java you have to remove * and change -> to .

Comment: Yes, and I will add that b2ContactListener doesn't exits (anymore maybe), the class is : ContactListener

Answer (score 0):

And take note, some solutions don't have shortcuts as always but you can find the right solution and there is possibly a hundred ways to detect a collision and you know it, don't you? This is like in the solution of  box2d collision detection program for example.

http://blog.allanbishop.com/box2d-2-1a-tutorial-%E2%80%93-part-4-collision-detection/